# Django: set number of ForeignKey relations by integer value in another model

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many

I am designing an Mturk application in Django where people rate Tweets for different outcomes (gender, personality, age, etc.). In my models I have three classes: Task (the Mturk task), Message (the Twitter message), and Outcome (the relationship I want the message annotated for). For each Task I want the ability to display a certain number of tweets. So for instance, if I want to know something about the Twitter user I might show 20 tweets but if I want to know something about a single tweet I will only show 1 tweet.

For each Outcome there will be multiple instances of Task and each Message should be able to be used in multiple Tasks (possibly each pointing to different Outcomes).

So my question is, given `num_of_tweets` in the Outcomes model, how can I have Tasks point to that number of Messages? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
class Outcomes(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    short_definition = models.TextField()
    detail_desc = models.TextField()
    num_of_tweets = models.Integer(default=1)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    outcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcomes, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    mturk_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Messages(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
```

My first thought was pick a max number of messages, say 5, and then have something like:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    outcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcomes, blank=True, null=True)
    message1 = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    message2 = models.ForeignKey(Message, blank=True, null=True)
    message3 = models.ForeignKey(Message, blank=True, null=True)
    message4 = models.ForeignKey(Message, blank=True, null=True)
    message5 = models.ForeignKey(Message, blank=True, null=True)
    mturk_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is tedious, especially since I know that some Outcomes should show up to 20 tweets.

Comment: Have you ever considered using nosql database for this task/project? You will benefit from agile table (document in nosql) structure.

Comment: No, will look into this. I'm kind of new to Django, databases and Mturk so I'm just building off of some preexisting code that I now need to generalize (which is why I'm adding the option of showing n number of tweets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on how you assign messages to tasks. However, if you need the ability to have multiple elements on each side of a relationship, you should use a ManyToManyField, not a ForeignKey.

Depending on what you are actually doing, you should be able to validate the correct number of messages according to `num_of_tweets` - for example, if you're assigning messages via a form, you can do the validation there.